# How can I return HTTP 403 from a template?

Tags: templating

I'm building a rough JSON API using normal Craft templates (i.e. rendering the JSON with Twig) but would like to be able to return HTTP 403 to unauthenticated requests.

For example:

```
{% if not user %}
    {% respond 403 %}
{% endif %}
```

Is something like this built in?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Exit tag](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/exit) is what you're looking for.

```
{% exit 403 %}
```

Comment: I actually didn't realise that worked for anything other than 404. My bad.

Comment: Next time you'll know :)

Comment: Every day's a school day.

Comment: @SteveAbraham Especially with Andris is the teacher.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a shot in the dark here, but it might be worth having a look at the [header tag](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/header), see if you can get that to do what you need...

Comment: Ignore my answer, do what Andris says, he's the man.